# Symmetric Roles of the two problem solutions in RINS

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

Currently, I am reading the paper "Exploring relaxation induced neighborhood to improve MIP solutions by Danna et.al. from 2004 and they are talking about a symmetric role of incumbent and the relaxed solution. Which I understood as following:

An incumbent of poor quality can be improved because the respective relaxation is leading into a good direction. And vice versa, a loose relaxation can be compensated by an incumbent of good quality.

How does it work? Can it not happen that it still continues into a completely bad direction?